# In AppScript, for Workspace Published Add-On Sheet Extensions, how do I switch to Head version and stop Deploying every bug fix?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

## **Each time I fix a bug I have to Deploy and update the Version**

**in the**
[**console.cloud.google.com**](https://console.cloud.google.com)
**I'm 17 Versions** in and I don't think this is how it's supposed to work.

**How do I switch back to Head so that I just Save the new code**, reload my sheet, and work with the updated code?

**I am the admin for the account**, so I had published the Extension as an Add-On in the Marketplace so people on the team could see the Extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can Test the add-on directly via 'Run' menu - 'Test as add-on' option.

Select the version on which you want to test and select the document.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilbES.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXqfy.png)